# Hide multi site network menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In wordpress multi-site network how we can restrict menu for different user ? e.g if i want to hide woocommerce menu then how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little broad but you can use members plugin to handle users permissions :

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/members/